# Switching between ubuntu/windows while operating system is running

Tags: linux

I have ubuntu and windows 7 on my computer. I was curious if it is possible to switch between the two operating systems while keeping the computer running.

In short
I'd like to be able to go to ubuntu to from windows and from ubuntu from windows without restarting computer

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question. Maybe you should try SuperUser.

Comment: Not possible with a dual boot. You would need a virtual machine.

Comment: No but I think this could be relevant to programmers.

Comment: Nope, it is afaik not possible, if you want to run both OS natively, only, if you run it in a VM

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. It is not possible.

You can set up multiple partitions and switch between them, but you need to restart the computer.

This is integral to the nature of operating systems in general.

## Edit:

I assume you are talking about running each OS natively, not using a virtual machine